# Swift - After Screen Updates - UIView to UIImage Conversion

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, core-animation

I am trying to create an `UIImage` that I will use to set the background for a `UICollectionViewCell`. I found this function to convert a `UIView` to `UIImage`:

```
func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImage
}
```

In my collection view cell function I do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

    //creating view
    let colour1 = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    let colour2 = UIColor.red.cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colour1, colour2]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    let gradientView = UIView(frame: contentView.bounds)
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    //converting UIView to UIImage
    let ccimage = imageWithView(view: gradientView)
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> View (0x7fe876e2d940, UIView) drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES
>   inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported

If I make `afterScreenUpdates: false` , then I get this error:

> [Snapshotting] Drawing a view that has not been rendered at least once
>   requires afterScreenUpdates: YES.

I'am really confused on how to approach this error. Am I calling the function in the wrong place?

Comment: try by adding `layoutIfNeeded` after that.

Comment: to my UIView? I added gradientView.layoutIfNeeded() and it still gives the same error

Comment: Try it with `cell`

Comment: I put cell.layoutIfNeeded()  and still same error

Comment: @awezmm Are you do this for set gradient background to collection view cell?

Comment: @awezmm I ment `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I wanted to do: ```cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: ccimage!)``` at the end. But the background just shows up as black bc of the error I guess.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I tried it and same error

Comment: @awezmm But why you need to convert gradientView to image and then set to cell background as a pattern image you can directly apply the gradient layer as cell background.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni How? By using ```cell.layer.insertSublayer```  ? I'm going to have rounded corners on my cells and the gradient layer will block that even if I put it at index 0. I just thought the easiest way to have a gradient background with rounded corners is to just set a gradient image as the background. I have tried looking for a good way that uses insertSublayer but I have not found any that work well with the rounded corners.

Comment: @awezmm Check my answer and try it.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one it's working code for (swift 4)**

In UICollectionView `cellForItemAt` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

    //creating view
    let colour1 = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    let colour2 = UIColor.red.cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colour1, colour2]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    let gradientView = UIView(frame: contentView.bounds)
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    //converting UIView to UIImage
    if cell.backgroundColor == nil{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:gradientView.gradient_image!)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Extension fro convert `UIView` to `UIImage`

```
extension UIView {

    var gradient_image: UIImage? {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        } else {

            // If Swift version is lower than 4.2,
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
            defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
            guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                return nil
            }
            self.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]